# Maximum bug-free and future compatibility: retarget to a higher .NET version?

Tags: c#, .net

Sorry if the question is not OK for this forum because answers might be a bit of 'opinion', just seeking advice...

I am working on a C# project including some Win32 C++ DLLs in VS 2015, target .NET 4.5.2. Someone on this forum called .NET 4.5 '*a buggy piece of crap*' (solved in .NET 4.5.2?), so I wonder if I should retarget to a newer .NET version to have my app maximally bug-free and compatible with future .NET developments.

And if I should retarget, to what version? I assume the higher the version I retarget to, the more customers will have to update their .NET, so is there a good compromise between '*version X is relatively bugfree and stable*' and '*you do not really need the higher version Y*'?

Comment: you should probably should target .NET 4.8 Framework (currently the latest) . I have never heard anyone say .NET 4.5 is particularly buggy.

Comment: The latest .NET Framework - i.e. 4.8.x. Also consider moving to a newer version of VS.

Comment: By default, always target the latest version. However, you should look at .NET Core rather than legacy .NET Framework if possible.

Comment: More often than not, when someone describes an OS, library, framework as "a buggy piece of crap", what they mean is that they ran their software on it, it exposed all kinds of latent bugs *in their software*, but they decided it must be someone else's fault.

Comment: Note that 4.8 is marked as a recommended update, so most Windows PC should've been automatically updated to it. It can be considered "stable", just like VB6 runtime is still supported even on Windows 10, decades later, since .NET Framework won't receive additional functionality update (only security patches), while each LTS of .NET Core have at most 3 years of support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it's a "buggy piece of crap", but each version generally fixes a number of issues, adds new features, and improves perfomance (GC and JIT in particular). Switching to .NET 4.8 would likely be as simple as installing VS2019, allowing it to update the project files as needed, and changing the project Framework version.

One thing to keep in mind is that [.NET 4.8 is likely the last version of .NET Framework](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/), so a more future proof approach would be to port the app to .NET Core. The next version of .NET is called .NET 5 (expected release date is 12/2020), and will be based on .NET Core.